# Creating deadlock situation with different actions (methods) on the same object?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have created the next simple class code (which is just for my question clarification):

```
public class StudioClass {

synchronized void dancing(String name) {
    System.out.println(name + " is dancing");
}

synchronized  void singing(String name) {
    System.out.println(name + " is singing");
}

public class StudentA extends Thread {
    String name;

    public StudentA(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        dancing(name);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        singing(name);
    }
}

public class StudentB extends Thread {
    String name;

    public StudentB(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        singing(name);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        dancing(name);
    }
}
```

In this example the order actions of **student A** are: *dancing and then singing* and **student B** are: *singing and than dancing*. This scenario is a classic situation for a `Deadlock`.

How can I deliberately create a `Deadlock` situation by these actions?
The simple solution (as I understand) is to define each action (singing & dancing) as different objects, but I wonder is there any other way keeping them as methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any potential deadlocks with your code.
A thread executes a single synchronized method and during this execution I don't see conditions which will make two threads to wait for each other in a indefinite way. 
At worst, a thread waits for that the other thread releases the lock on the method. 
You should imagine a more complex scenario with share object between threads or inter-dependencies between actions.

Comment: What I mean is studentA performs action x then action y and studentB performs action y first and then action x. Is there any way getting a deadlock from this scenario?

Comment: in you scenario, each thread waits for its turn. To have a deadlock, you scenario must suppose that two threads may wait for each other to go on.
You should imagine a more complex scenario with share object between threads or inter-dependencies between actions.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using any shared resource. Without that there's no question of a deadlock.
If there was a situation like A, B both require a lock on shared variables s,t to perform a dance and song and the locks were acquired in the following way (among others):

A_lock(s)
A_lock(t)
dance
sing
A_release(t)
A_release(s)

B_lock(t)
B_lock(s)
dance
sing
B_release(s)
B_release(t)

There is a chance of deadlock if A acquires s and B acquires t and wait for each other to release locks for eternity.